# Decision to make a class static

Tags: java, design-patterns, static

I have the server project that I have seperated into 6 different  classes:

- ServerConnectionManager - is class is ment to be the hub for all other classes
- Connection - This object is the created whenever a client connects and also starts a Thread
- ServerListner - This is the Thread class that listens to input from the user
- ServerSender - This is the class that sends messages to one or more users
- ServerInformation - this class contains two list one of chat persons and one of connections this class also allows you to search through the list to find a specefic person and or connection
- ChatPerson - This object is to contain the username of each person who connects to the server

As you no-doubt have guessed by now this is a server for a chat program!

My question to you is:

I want to use the Design patteren (Mediator) on this project and therefore the ServerConnectionManager contains all the key methods that each of the classes use. for example adding a connection to the connection list in the ServerInformation class.

But since the ServerInformation class cannot be called an object seeing as it only have alot of methods (functions) and no real purpose other than storing and searching Data would it be a good idea to make it static? or should i stick to the plan and make everything go through the ServerConnectionManager?

Here is a sample of my code:

**ServerConnectionManager**

```
public class ServerConnectionManager {

    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection;
    private static ServerInformation ai = new ServerInformation();
    private static boolean connected = false;
    private static final int portNumber = 7070;
    private static int backLog = 100;

    /**
     * This method launches the server (and the application)!
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args){
        startServer();
        waitForConnection();
    }


    /**
     *This method sets the serverSocket to portNumber and also adds the backLog.
     */
    private static void startServer() {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(portNumber, backLog);
            connected = true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    /**
     * This method waits for a connection aslong as the serverSocket is connected.
     * When a new client connects it creates an Object of the connection and starts the individual procedure.
     */
    private static void waitForConnection() {
        while (connected) {
            try {
                connection = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Connection c = new Connection(connection);
            addConnection(c);
            waitForConnection();
        }

    }


    public static void closeMe(Socket con) {
        for (Connection conn : ai.getConnectionList()) {
            if (conn.getConnection() == con) {
                ai.getList().remove(ai.getList().indexOf(ai.getChatPersonByConnection(con)));
                ai.getConnectionList().remove(conn);

                System.out.println(ai.getList());
                System.out.println(ai.getConnectionList());
                conn.close();
                break;

            }
        }

    }
    public static void addConnection(Connection con){
        ai.addToConnectionList(con);

    }
    public static void addChatPerson(ChatPerson p){
        ai.add(p);
        System.out.println(ai.getList());
    }



}
```

**Connection**

```
public class Connection{
    private Socket connection;
    public Connection(Socket connection){
        this.connection = connection;
        ServerListner cl = new ServerListner(Connection.this);
        cl.start();
    }
    public Socket getConnection(){
        return this.connection;
    }
    public void close() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

**ServerListner**

```
public class ServerListner extends Thread {

    private Socket connection;
    private BufferedReader br;
    private ChatPerson person;
    private Connection con;
    private ServerInformation ai = new ServerInformation();
    private ServerSender sender = new ServerSender();

    public ServerListner(Connection con){
        this.con = con;
        connection = con.getConnection();
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Socket getConnection(){
        return this.connection;
    }
    public void run(){
        System.out.println(con.getConnection().isConnected());
            try {
                String inString;
                while ((inString = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (inString.equalsIgnoreCase("Disconnect")) {
                        System.out.println(inString);
                        break;
                    }else {
                        processInput(inString);
                    }
                }
                ServerConnectionManager.closeMe(connection);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    public void processInput(String input){
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Connect")) {
            sender.sendMessageToConnection(this.connection, "Accepted");
        }
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("UserInformation")) {
            try {
                String username = br.readLine();
                person = new ChatPerson(username, connection);
                ServerConnectionManager.addChatPerson(person);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("SearchByCon")) {
            String name = ai.searchByConnection(connection);
            System.out.println(name);
        }

    }
}
```

**ServerSender**

```
public class ServerSender {
    private PrintWriter pw;
    private ServerInformation ai = new ServerInformation();

    public void addToList(){

    }
    public void sendToAll(String message){
        for (Connection c : ai.getConnectionList()) {
            try {
                pw = new PrintWriter(c.getConnection().getOutputStream());
                pw.print(message);
                pw.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
    /** 
     *
     * @param con
     * @param message
     */

    /*
     * Note - Denne metode gør også at jeg kan hviske til folk!:)
     */
    public void sendMessageToConnection(Socket con, String message){
        try {
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            print.println(message);
            print.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

**ServerInformation**

```
public class ServerInformation{
    private ArrayList<Connection> connectedClients = new ArrayList<Connection>();
    private ArrayList<ChatPerson> list = new ArrayList<ChatPerson>();


    public ArrayList<Connection> getConnectionList(){
        return connectedClients;
    }
    public void addToConnectionList(Connection con){
        connectedClients.add(con);
    }
    public String searchByConnection(Socket myConnection){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getConnection() == myConnection) {
                return p.getName();
            }   
        }
        /*
         * If none found!
         */
        return null;
    }

    public ChatPerson getChatPersonByConnection(Socket myConnection){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getConnection() == myConnection) {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void add(ChatPerson p){
        list.add(p);
    }

    public void removeByName(String name){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                list.remove(p);     
            }
        }
    }
    public String searchList(String name){
        for (ChatPerson p : list) {
            if (p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return p.getName();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }   
    public ArrayList<ChatPerson>getList(){
        return list;
    }

}
```

**ChatPerson**

```
public class ChatPerson {
    private String chatName;
    private Socket connection;

    /*
     * This is for furture development
     * private Integer adminLevel;
     */

    public ChatPerson(String name, Socket connection){
        this.chatName = name;
        this.connection = connection;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.chatName = name;

    }
    public String getName(){
        return chatName;

    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Username: "+chatName;
    }
    public Socket getConnection(){
        return connection;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance, by the way since i am a student it would be nice if you had time to rate my code aswell and come with suggestions on how i can improve (if there are any :))

Comment: You can also read this http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2012/03/02/When-To-Use-The-Static-Keyword-In-Net.aspx  Nevermind the .net part is just C# but the concepts apply to java too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant class with only static methods, not static class. Static inner classes are something different (you can google it).

Advantages of having non-static methods in your manager:

- You can easily mock them with frameworks like Mockito during testing.
- You can pull them up to some interface during refactoring of your code.
- Using static methods is not object-oriented-programming as such method invocations are not associated with any instance (object) of your class.

Comment: So what your saying is that the ServerInformation should not be static and that i should instance it in my ServerManager and call all methods through the Manager? The problem im having is that if all my objects and classes have their own instance of ServerInformation then they wont be able to use that class at all? seeing as all the lists will have different instances of eachother